# How to disable to default hover color change on the rows of grids in Ext Js 4.0?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I want to **disable** the default hover color(grey) change that occurs on the **rows of the grid** in **Ext Js 4.0.** How can I do it?

Comment: Try `.x-grid-row-over {background-color:transparent !important;}`.

Comment: Or even better: try `viewConfig:{overItemCls:''}` on the grid.

Answer (score 4):

To remove the hover color you need to make changes in the viewConfig.

```
viewConfig : {
    trackOver : false
}
```

This will disable the hover from the grid

Documentation: [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.View-cfg-trackOver)